# Python Mechanize not submitting, but works on computer?

Tags: python, mechanize

Ok so I have a server (hosted by Godaddy which is runny python 2.4.3, Red Hat) and on that server I want to go to another site via my python script and login and perform a task then logout simple right? The problem is that when I run it, the login doesn't submit. The weird thing is when I run the script on my computer (running python 2.7.2, Mac OS X) it works perfectly submits and everything (and yes the scripts are the exact same). Here is my script:

```
browser.open("website")
browser.select_form(name="form_name")
browser.form['theAccountName']= username
browser.form['theAccountPW'] = password
browser.submit()
```

Any nudge in the right direction will help been stuck on this for days.

It may also be important to note, I am not sure why, that I wasn't able to "install" mechanize on my server do to Godaddy's restrictions. I instead put it in the same folder for it to import.

Thanks.